# How to set condition in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT partnumber, p.partdescription, i.invoicenumber, id.quantity, p.interchangeno, p.makemodelname , c.rte
FROM Invoice i,
     invoicedetails id,
     Parts p,
     customer c  
WHERE i.customerid = c.customerid 
  AND i.invoicenumber = id.invoicenumber
  AND i.invoicenumber 
  AND id.partnumber = p.partNo
  AND p.UnitsInStock < 0 AND id.quantity > 0;
```

In this query how to set condition that if interchangeNo is empty then above is right if interchangeNo is not empty then select interchangeNo as partNo

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a case statement -

```
SELECT partnumber, p.partdescription, i.invoicenumber, id.quantity,
       CASE WHEN p.interchangeno IS NULL THEN p.interchangeno
            ELSE partNo END interchangeno, p.makemodelname , c.rte
FROM Invoice i
JOIN invoicedetails id ON i.invoicenumber = id.invoicenumber
JOIN Parts p ON id.partnumber = p.partNo
JOIN customer c ON i.customerid = c.customerid 
WHERE p.UnitsInStock < 0 AND id.quantity > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp and http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-if-else/

```
SELECT  p.interchangeno
FROM Invoice i,
     invoicedetails id,
     Parts p,
     customer c  
WHERE i.customerid = c.customerid 
  AND i.invoicenumber = id.invoicenumber
  AND i.invoicenumber 
  AND id.partnumber = p.partNo
  AND p.UnitsInStock < 0 AND id.quantity > 0;
if (p.interchangeno =0)
SELECT partnumber, p.partdescription, i.invoicenumber, id.quantity, p.interchangeno, p.makemodelname , c.rte
FROM Invoice i,
     invoicedetails id,
     Parts p,
     customer c  
WHERE i.customerid = c.customerid 
  AND i.invoicenumber = id.invoicenumber
  AND i.invoicenumber 
  AND id.partnumber = p.partNo
  AND p.UnitsInStock < 0 AND id.quantity > 0;

else
-- code that you want
```

I'm pretty sure that this can be improved, but what you're missing is the if else

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` query for connecting multiple tables, there is lot of examples for learning that.

Your query will be like below if you have written query using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT `INV_DTL`.`partnumber`, `P`.`partdescription`, `INV`.`invoicenumber`, `INV_DTL`.`quantity`, 
    (CASE WHEN `P`.`interchangeno` IS NULL THEN interchangeno_is_null ELSE interchangeno_is_not_null END) AS interchangeno, `P`.`makemodelname`, `C`.`rte` 
FROM `invoice` INV 
JOIN `invoicedetails` INV_DTL ON (`INV_DTL`.`invoicenumber` = `INV`.`invoicenumber`) 
JOIN `parts` P ON (`P`.`partNo` = `INV_DTL`.`partnumber`) 
JOIN `customer` C ON (`C`.`customerid` = `INV`.`customerid`) 
WHERE `P`.`UnitsInStock` < 0 AND `INV_DTL`.`quantity` > 0;
```

A helpful [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to learn `JOIN` query.

You only need below query part for filling your issue:

```
CASE WHEN `P`.`interchangeno` IS NULL THEN interchangeno_is_null ELSE interchangeno_is_not_null END
```

Please use the required value on `interchangeno_is_null` & `interchangeno_is_not_null`.

The `CASE` statement goes through conditions and returns a value when the first condition is met (like an `IF-THEN-ELSE` statement). So, once a condition is true, it will stop reading and return the result.
If no conditions are true, it returns the value in the `ELSE` clause.

The syntax is like:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

A helpful [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) to learn `CASE` statement.

Comment: `CASE WHEN P.interchangeno IS NULL THEN P.interchangeno ELSE partNo END` would not ever return a non-NULL `P.interchangeno`...

Comment: Also `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()` is shorter for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `IFNULL()`.

```
SELECT partnumber, p.partdescription, i.invoicenumber, id.quantity, 
       IFNULL(p.interchangeno,p.partnumber), p.makemodelname , c.rte
FROM Invoice i join invoicedetails id on i.invoicenumber = id.invoicenumber
      join Parts p on .... -- join condition goes here
      join customer c  on ... --join condition goes here
WHERE p.UnitsInStock < 0 AND id.quantity > 0
```

As mentioned above,always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax as shown in my query

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the JOIN syntax.
The comma syntax was already outdated by the end of the last century.

And then you can use `LEFT JOIN`
And a `CASE` allows a bit of logic.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN p.partNo IS NULL
THEN id.partnumber
WHEN p.interchangeno IS NOT NULL
THEN id.partnumber 
ELSE p.partNo
END AS partNo,
p.partdescription, 
i.invoicenumber, 
id.quantity, 
p.interchangeno, 
p.makemodelname,
c.rte
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN invoicedetails id
  ON id.invoicenumber = i.invoicenumber
INNER JOIN customer c  
  ON c.customerid = i.customerid 
LEFT JOIN Parts p
  ON p.partNo = id.partnumber
 AND p.UnitsInStock < 0
WHERE id.quantity > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE()` (or its MySQL version `IFNULL()`), something like this:

```
SELECT partnumber, p.partdescription, i.invoicenumber, id.quantity, p.interchangeno,
       p.makemodelname, c.rte
FROM Invoice i
  JOIN invoicedetails id ON i.invoicenumber = id.invoicenumber
    JOIN Parts p         ON id.partnumber = COALESCE(p.interchangeno, p.partNo)
      JOIN customer c    ON i.customerid = c.customerid
WHERE p.UnitsInStock < 0
  AND id.quantity > 0
```